# windowSplashScreenAnimatableIcon not found

Tags: android, splash-screen, styling, android-12

I want to customize my splash screen on Android 12 and I get the AAPT error:

```
AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimatableIcon' not found.
```

Here is the relevant part of the style:

```xml
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatableIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
</style>
```

That is the attribute mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#implement).

Here is an overview of the build tool libs I'm using:

```
compileSdk="android-S"
minSdk=21
targetSdk="S"
buildTools='31.0.0-rc4'
```

I use Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 1 just for the records.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Related bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188565331

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the documentation is wrong/outdated. The right attribute is:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
```

The correct attribute is listed in the [`R.attr` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr?hl=en#windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon).

---

In a previous version of this answer I had a way to keep the splashscreen working as before, however this does not work anymore.

Today I suggest to use the splash compat library and this style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/ic_launcher_background</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Your.Normal.Theme</item>
</style>
```

This has the two assumptions that you use a adaptive launcher icon with the default namings. In my case `ic_launcher_background` is a solid color this is why I'm using color instead of drawable prefix. I hope that helps others.

Here is the guide for the [splash migration](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/splash-screen-migration) from Google.

Comment: I was composing an answer. Guess you were faster.

Comment: FWIW, in Beta 2, the `@null` icon does not seem to be working -- the app icon still shows up.

Comment: @rekire Is this still working? I've tried this with my existing splash drawable, but I can only see the colour, but not the drawable, on the SplashScreen. Here is my code: 
My values-v31 styles.xml file:
``` language-all
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: It seems that you can keep with the compat library the splash screen behavior on older platforms, however on newer platforms that does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has issues customising splash screen make sure you are using the correct **parent theme**

Instead of

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatableIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
</style>
```

use

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatableIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Your.Normal.Theme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: There is no such a theme. Unless you use a new dependency of it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate#migrate_your_splash_screen_implementation , but then your minimal API should be at least 21. Also, you mean windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon. Not what you wrote.