# AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenBackground' not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I've got the very same error, using Android Studio Canary.

It returns the same error in Gradle 4.2.1 and Gradle latest version 7.1.0-alpha09.  (i.e. error log is bellow)

```
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
ERROR:/home/iuri/QonteoApps/biometricmax/node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android/build/intermediates/packaged_res/release/values/values.xml:13:5-18:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenBackground' not found.
    
ERROR:/home/iuri/QonteoApps/biometricmax/node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android/build/intermediates/packaged_res/release/values/values.xml:13:5-18:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon' not found.
    
ERROR:/home/iuri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/de2ed04f8522efd4ca22835ece62dd33/transformed/core-splashscreen-1.0.0-alpha01/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon' not found.
    
ERROR:/home/iuri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/de2ed04f8522efd4ca22835ece62dd33/transformed/core-splashscreen-1.0.0-alpha01/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenBackground' not found.
    
ERROR:/home/iuri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/de2ed04f8522efd4ca22835ece62dd33/transformed/core-splashscreen-1.0.0-alpha01/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration' not found.

at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
```

Furthermore, I've updated:

1. SDK Platform to Android 12(S).
2. Plus SDK Build Tools is updated to Android SDK Build-Tools 31

Where/How must I implement those style attributes?
I've added the following items to Styles.xml

```xml
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
```

Comment: btw, the original post, which led me to this solution approach is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598533/windowsplashscreenanimatableicon-not-found#_=_

Comment: I tried everything correctly, but error was never resolved, wasted hours..

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a duplicate of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183863/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-the-proper-way-i-e-not-to-make-it-a-part-of-the-app)

I guess you didn't change the *theme parent*.

With the latest update, Android 12 comes with `SplashScreen API` to ensure the splash screen displays correctly starting in Android 12.

To access that you have to upgrade your *gradle* file and change your *theme parent* to `Theme.SplashScreen`. In your gradle add:

```
android {
    //before syncing please make sure Android API 12 is installed in SDK manager
    compileSdkVersion 31 
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
    ...
}
```

Create a separate `style.xml` for the splash screen

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MySplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen"> 
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item> <!-- If it's a @drawable make sure it's in .xml format-->
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/books_logo</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Books</item> <!-- This will switch back to your given theme once the splash screen is gone-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Set the theme in your manifest `<application>`

```
<manifest>
   <application 
   ...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplashScreen">
   ...
```

**Finally** in `MainActivity` or your start activity to load the splash screen set this in `onCreate()` before `setContentView()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()

        setContentView(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did change theme parent within AndroidManifest.xml.

After a long time debugging and burning neurons, I switched to another react-native pluggin called bootsplash. https://www.reactnativeschool.com/simple-splash-launch-boot-screen-in-react-native-ios-and-android

It seems react-native-splashscreen's core (i.e. latest version 3.2.0) has a bug within JAVA's native source code.

Best wishes,
I